# Safe functions in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015

While coding C under windows,visual studio 2015,I found my self forced to amend my code due to the deprecated functions,by adding a second parameter,and of course using a safe function(e.g. ending with _s).

I was wondering,do these functions exist in the C standard library,and will i be able to compile them with a C compiler if I transfer them to my linux partition?

My concern arose when i was writing a string flip about an offset function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *flipstr(char *str, size_t size, size_t offset);

int main(int , char **)
{
    char str[] = "JonSon";
    char *p = flipstr(str, sizeof(str), 3);
    if (p) {
        printf("%s\n", p);
    }
    return 0;
}

char *flipstr(char *str, size_t size, size_t offset)
{
    if (offset > strlen(str)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    char *tmp = (char *)calloc(size, sizeof(char));

    strncpy_s(tmp, size, str, offset);

    memmove(str, str + offset, strlen(str + offset));

    memcpy(str + strlen(str + offset), tmp, strlen(tmp));

    free(tmp);

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Just use `std::string`.

Comment: It seems that [strncpy_c](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) was introduced with C++11.

Comment: You can defeat the MSVC compiler warnings by placing `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before the `#include` header definitions

Comment: I don't consider `scanf_s` to be any safer than `scanf` anyway. It's trickier to use and just as easy to get it wrong, possibly with worse consequences since if the arguments are incorrectly aligned a small "size" value can be used as a pointer - horrible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, most of them aren't standard and you shouldn't use them just because somebody in Microsoft decided to "deprecate" half the standard library in favor of their non-standard extensions. Sure, there is some justification of what they did, but in the end it's simply ridiculous. You are better to disable the warnings and write a portable C/C++.

Comment: I seem to remember that Microsoft made the safe functions available as a portable header library. Not sure though. Upvoted your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here...

First of all, [there is nothing wrong with using `strcpy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23490019/584518), that's a myth. And it is not deprecated, that's just Microsoft gaga.

Second, [`strncpy` was never intended to be a safe version of `strcpy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-are-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-insecure). It was never intended to be used for anything but an old, non-standard string format in ancient Unix.

Third, `strncpy` is unsafe and dangerous. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869883/why-is-strncpy-insecure) and [this](http://blog.liw.fi/posts/strncpy/). Plenty of blogs about this to be found.

So forget about `strncpy`, and consequently, also forget about `strncpy_s`. There is actually a function called `strncpy_s` in the C11 bounds-checking interface (which isn't mandatory for compilers to implement).

If this C11 standard function is fully compatible with non-standard Microsoft junk functions with the same name, I have no idea. I wouldn't count on it. But since Visual Studio 2015 is an ancient compiler from the early 90s, C11 is not something you can use anyhow.

Comment: "Visual Studio 2015 is an ancient compiler from the early 90s", uh? Visual C++ 2015 supports almost all of the C++14 standard.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 does not date from the early 90s.   It is the 2015 release, albeit earlier releases date back a fair way.   By your logic, a significant number of mainstream compilers should not be used, because they have a lineage dating back several years.

Comment: This is tagged C and the code is C. The _C compiler_ inside Visual Studio is from the early 90s. It does not conform to C99 let alone the current C standard, which was released 5 years ago.